# Cheap O365 subscription recommendation

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365

I want an O365 subscription where I can develop as many intranet sites as I want, with feature publish, and test some apps, as well as have my online SharePoint site as well. What's the best subscription for this purpose?

I can see that all subscriptions include the same thing, so do I get small business with one user? will it contain publishing sites? will I develop apps? is there any other option?

Comment: Are your focus to publish as many sites as possible, or to develop different features for O365?

Comment: Thanks Benny, I want to develop for O365, like Apps, workflows, to make multiple internal site collections with publishing enabled, and have one public website to test anonymous stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely get an Office 365 developer subscription. The subscription is pre-configured for development purposes (using the developer site collection as the default), and includes all of the features of the top tier enterprise solution (publishing features, InfoPath forms support, etc). Plus you get access to the full Office 365 application suite to install if you want, as well as Exchange online for development purposes.

Cost is currently $99.00 (USD) per year, so you'll pay $8.25 each month -- which is the best value for access to the level of services you'll receive.

You can sign up here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179924(v=office.15).aspx

Additional notes:

- You can develop workflows and use SharePoint Designer on the developer subscription
- Public websites on SharePoint online are going away in general there are other options available but likely not using SharePoint hosted by Microsoft; see this MS KB article: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3027254/en-us
- You only get 1 subscription per developer account, but it is possible to add other user entities in your Active Directory for testing

Comment: Thanks John. Will I be able to do public website with it? Will I be able to test emails from workflows in SharePoint designer?

Comment: but you don't get Exchange email with developer subscription, right?

Comment: You do get exchange email with the developer subscription, it costs extra with the other plans.

Comment: Thanks John. And if I want to add another user to test as contributor, can I do that?

Comment: "Will I be able to do public website with it?". Forget about this - it is dropped beginning January 2015 http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3027254

Comment: I've integrated all of my comments and displayName's into the answer -- thanks for adding that info btw, I know there had been rumors brewing on that.